# How to account for repeated measures of samples through time in using mixed effect models

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I have an experiment where I repeatedly took sediment samples from inside and outside of the same plots in spring and summer for 3 years. For example, sample_IA represents a sample  from inside plot A and I collected represents the same sample collect in summer 2020.

I want to know if the proportion of silt in sediments differ inside and outside of plots within each season and across seasons

response variable: proportion silt

factor 1: location (inside or outside of plots)

factor 2: time (season when samples were collected, e.g. spring 2020, summer 2020,.....)

random effects (samples collected from inside and outside each plot)

This is my first attempt at the code

```
lmer(prop_silt ~ location * time + (1|location/sample))
```

Does this seem correct?

Answer (score 2):

With some exceptions, you shouldn't have the same term in the model as both a fixed effect and a *grouping variable* (right side of the bar in a `(f|g)` random-effect term); you have `location` in both places.

Maybe try `prop_silt ~ location * time + (1|location:sample))` (here only the *interaction* of `location` and `sample` is included).